# cors settings in https

Tags: ssl, https, cors, mean

My node applications runs fine with http but in https it throws cors error and my ssl port link (https://www.example.com:3001) works fine and loads.. So ssl settings are fine but the cors issue is not allowing to submit the form..

The following is the code for http which is working fine.. Can anyone check and fix the issue..

```js
var express = require('express');

var DataController = require('./user/DataController');
var UserController = require('./user/UserController');
var db = require('./database/dbbase-db'); 
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});


app.use('/user', UserController);
app.use('/data', DataController);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Welcome");
});

var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.crt'),
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("Welcome");
}).listen(3001);

// app.listen(3001, function () {
// console.log('Welcome')
// })
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked and here is the updated code:

```js
var express = require('express');
var DataController = require('./user/DataController');
var UserController = require('./user/UserController');
var db = require('./database/database-db'); 
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://www.example.com");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
next();
});

app.use('/user', UserController);
app.use('/data', DataController);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send("Welcome");
});

// This settings are for HTTPS, SSL web applications

var https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("key.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.crt")
 };
https.createServer(options,app).listen(3001);
console.log('Welcome')



// // This settings are only for HTTP sites

// var http = require("http");
// var fs = require("fs");

// http.createServer(app).listen(3001);
// console.log('Welcome')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ports if there is firewall rules or there's other listing on the the same port

Comment: There are no error in the server logs and the port URL (example.com:3001) loads perfect, base URL and all the services have https and loads fine BUT form submission we get the cors error in chrome browser as well as FF.. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'example.com:3001/user/findUser' from origin 'example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: If server is fine in port and Application script  and error generated in browser side this maybe related to ssl certificate itself try to install it again or check directory permissions witch you have stored it at  or change directory to another one

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... Finally it worked and I posted the working code..